# Using validator.js for Bootstrap dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am unable to figure out a way to use the validator.js bootstrap library http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/ for a Bootstrap dropdown. It works for all other fields but it doesn't work for the dropdown. There may be a way to do it but I don't know how. Here is my dropdown code.

```
<div class="dropdown" >
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a number   
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
    <li><a id="a_5" href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_4" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_3" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_2" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_1" href="#">1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to show an example in the documentation, if you are using Html5 you could change it to use the select tag with the required attribute if that was an option, here it is here.

```html
<form >
    <select required>
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: I thought about this but the Bootstrap drop down looks much nicer and i'm trying to get validations work for that component.

Comment: Also if I club it along with the Bootstrap components this validation doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the shown code in within a `<form>` on which Bootstrap validator is instanciated.

```
<div class="dropdown" >
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a number   
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
    <li><a id="a_5" href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_4" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_3" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_2" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_1" href="#">1</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" id="dropdownSelected" class="form-control"></input>
</div>

<script>
$('.dropdown li').on('click', function(){
    $('#dropdownSelected').val($(this).text());
});
</script>
```

Now what should be validated is the hidden input.
;)

Comment: Wow, that was a TERRIFIC out of the box idea, it should work but it doesn't seem to work. I added a required on the input tag and that should be it right?

Comment: mmm. And no error in console? Can you give me a live link?

Comment: Well, I can't do much... Can you create a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) with your code to reproduce the issue ?